# Handing + / -ve filters in map<string,set>

Tags: java

Before asking the question, I want to tell that my experience in Java(10+ exp on PHP).

I have written a code which works perfectly fine for me but the line of code is just too much. Can someone help me how to improve the performance and quality of code here?

https://ideone.com/EfoVMC

Case1:

```
Map<String, String> mapViewFromProperties = new HashMap<>();
mapViewFromProperties.put("bi", "aa,bb");
mapViewFromProperties.put("n", "xx,yy");
Set<String> filter = new HashSet<String>();
filter.add("bi.aa");
filter.add("bi.cc");
filter.add("-bi.bb"); /*remove key bi value bb*/
```

output :

```
{bi=[aa, cc], n=[xx, yy]}
```

Case2:

```
Map<String, String> mapViewFromProperties = new HashMap<>();
mapViewFromProperties.put("bi", "aa,bb");
mapViewFromProperties.put("n", "xx,yy");
Set<String> filter = new HashSet<String>();
filter.add("xx.cc");
filter.add("-n");   /*completely remove key n*/
```

output :

```
{xx=[cc], bi=[aa, bb]}
{bi=[aa, cc], n=[xx, yy]}
```

Case3:
if all child gets deleted, the parent should also be deleted (haven't handle the case now).

Question: Though my code is running perfectly fine but the quality seems bad. Can someone please help.

Source code: https://ideone.com/EfoVMC

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here

        Map<String, HashSet<String>> FinalMap = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();
        Map<String, String> mapViewFromProperties = new HashMap<>();
        mapViewFromProperties.put("bi", "aa,bb");
        mapViewFromProperties.put("n", "xx,yy");

        Set<String> filter = new HashSet<String>();
        filter.add("bi.aa");
        filter.add("bi.cc");
        filter.add("-bi.bb");


        if (mapViewFromProperties != null && !mapViewFromProperties.isEmpty()) {
            mapViewFromProperties.forEach((key, value) -> {
                String[] values = value.split(",");
                HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(values));
                FinalMap.put(key, hashSet);
            });

            Map<String, HashSet<String>> finalViewNegate = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();
            if (!filter.isEmpty()) {
                for (String newStr : filter) {
                    if (newStr.startsWith("-")) {
                        newStr = newStr.substring(1);
                        if (newStr.contains(".")) {
                            String[] parts1 = newStr.split("\\.");
                            String key1, val1;
                            key1 = parts1[0];
                            val1 = parts1[1];

                            if (key1 != null && finalViewNegate.containsKey(key1)) {
                                HashSet<String> set1 = finalViewNegate.get(key1);
                                set1.add(val1);
                                finalViewNegate.put(key1, set1);
                            }
                            else {
                                HashSet<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>();
                                set1.add(val1);
                                finalViewNegate.put(key1, set1);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            HashSet<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>();
                            finalViewNegate.put(newStr, set1);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        String key;
                        String val;

                        if (newStr.contains(".")) {
                            String[] parts = newStr.split("\\.");
                            key = parts[0];
                            val = parts[1];

                            if (key != null && FinalMap.containsKey(key)) {
                                HashSet<String> set = FinalMap.get(key);
                                set.add(val);
                                FinalMap.put(key, set);
                            }
                            else {
                                HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
                                set.add(val);
                                FinalMap.put(key, set);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            /**
            * finalView = finalView - finalViewNegate
            */
            if (finalViewNegate != null && !finalViewNegate.isEmpty()) {
                finalViewNegate.forEach((key, value) -> {
                    String lr = key;
                    if (value.isEmpty()) {
                        String noUses1 = "1";
                        FinalMap.remove(key);
                        String noUses2 = "1";
                    }
                    else {
                        for (String val : value) {
                            if (FinalMap.containsKey(key)) {
                                HashSet<String> set = FinalMap.get(key);
                                set.remove(val);
                                FinalMap.put(key, set);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    String noUses = "1";
                });
            }
        }
        System.out.println("---->"+FinalMap.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: why is FinalMap named this way (capitalized)? it is very confusing...

Comment: in the output of 2nd case, you have 2 lines. probably meant the first one only (forgot to delete copy-paste origin?)

Comment: what's with the `noUses...` and `lr` vars??

Comment: What is the purpose of your code? Why do you store multiple values (`aa`, `bb`) in a single string? Why do you want a small filter 'language' instead of a set of methods (such as `addValue(String key, String value)` and `removeValue(String key, String value)`, instead of having to parse `"key.value"` and `"-key.value"`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the quality of the code is indeed not very good.  The first and foremost reason is that all the algorithm is coded in one, long, winding, spaghetti-smelling piece of code. in addition, the variable names a non descriptive and there is shortage of comments.

Start by breaking up this code into logical pieces:
`initFinalMap()`, `applyFilter()`, `applyNegation()` (you will need to figure out the args) The three methods should be broken down further.

furthermore, You need to use methods in order to give meaning to technical pieces of code. For instance this line
`if (newStr.startsWith("-")) {`
First of all, `newStr`? come on... how hard is it to call it `filter` or `filterEntry`? (no need for `Str`, we can see its type)

but what does the line mean? why are you asking about the first character? ok, you want to know if the subsquent String is to be added or substracted, right? so why not make a method `determineFilterOperation(String filterValue)` that returns an `OPERATION` enum that has `{ADD, SUBSTRACT}` values and then you can have a separate method that accepts `OPERATION` enum and performs the actual operation.

The benefit of this design is that you are better prepared for new operation requirment like `filter.add("#bi.bb");` which will mean... I don't know, something.

Now that I think of it, perhaps you can add the identifying character to the enum values and then in `determineFilterOperation` you extract the first character and search for the matching enum, which is a behavior of the enum:

```
public static enum FILTER_OPERATION
{
    ADD('+'),  // default operation
    SUBSTRACT('-');

    private char inputChar;

    FILTER_OPERATION(char inputChar) {
        this.inputChar = inputChar;
    }

    /**
     * returns operation that matches given arg
     * @param inputChar {@code char} first char from filter entry
     * @return matching {@code FILTER_OPERATION}, or {@code FILTER_OPERATION.ADD} if no match found
     */
    public static FILTER_OPERATION getOperation(char inputChar) {
        return Arrays.stream(FILTER_OPERATION.values())
                .filter(op -> op.inputChar == inputChar).findFirst().orElse(ADD);
    }
}
```

a whole new class out of one line of code...